# spree 2.2.1 add sale price to product

Tags: e-commerce, spree

I'm trying to find working gem for spree 2.2.1 to be able to add sale price to some products. The only solution i've found is https://github.com/jonathandean/spree-sale-pricing which is for spree version 2.0.0

It is little bit of surprise that current version of spree doesn't have this functionality by default, as this is one of the first things you want to do while running a online store.

Can anyone point me to right direction how to solve this issue without writing my own solution?

Comment: Sounds like a job for promotions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ways

1 - (simple) https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html - in oficial guide described simple solution for your task

2 - You can fork and update this gem https://github.com/jonathandean/spree-sale-pricing for own needs.

Best regards!